# Vue subdomain in development & production

Tags: docker, vue.js, configuration, subdomain, devops

I'm have following (abstract) project structure:

- src/brands
- src/admin
- src/home

Brands & admin are a pure vue project, home is a nuxt project. I'm trying to get the brands & admin project to run on their own subdomain (brands.website.com & admin.website.com, respectively), and home on the main domain. The deploy to production/staging happens via docker (with an nginx image), and I was thinking to just copy a nginx config file from my project to the docker image to point the files in the dist folder to the correct html file (not sure how yet, I need to research that first).

For development, I used vue.config.js (since I'm using v3 of the vue cli) and I have setup the following:

```
index: {
  entry: 'src/index/main.js',
  filename: 'index.html',
},
brands: {
  entry: 'src/brands/main.js',
  filename: 'brands/index.html',
},
admin: {
  entry: 'src/admin/main.js',
  filename: 'admin/index.html',
},
```

I can reach the brands module via localhost:8080/brands, admin module via localhost:8080/admin and the homepage via localhost:8080, but the problem is that on my index page I'm gonna have a route that is /brands, so that would probably overwrite the brands module route with the page from nuxt (or vice versa). Now is my question if there is a better way of doing this (for example to enable subdomains in vue / localhost) and if not, is the way I'm wanting to copy the nginx config to my docker image a good practice? Or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a clean, maintainable and scalable architecture, each app must have their own source repository,  server and domain. Why all your applications are in one src? If you split them, a simple nginx configuration could be enough to publish your three domains

Comment: I know, we have 5 services currently, each sitting in their own repo, but for frontend we wanted to use 1 repository and on production/staging I can use the method I described with the nginx conf, but I'm not sure how do use it in development on localhost.

Comment: Could you please post the configuration of your vue.config.js file that solves the subdomain issue?

Comment: I don't have that laying around anymore since we switched to nuxt and the subdomains are not there anymore. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar project architecture. I have a single repo with multiple vue/nuxt projects. Each of my projects is its own npm/webpack project and is accessed by subdomain when developing locally.

Based on your example, this is how I would setup the projects.

Modify your hosts file:

`127.0.0.1 website.localhost brands.website.localhost admin.website.localhost`

Using `localhost` as the TLD was my personal decision, feel free to name the domains anyway you like.

Configure webpack dev server to serve each project at the corresponding subdomain + port.

- src/brands: https://brands.website.localhost:8080
- src/admin:  https://admin.website.localhost:8081
- src/home:   https://website.localhost:8082

Whats nice about this configuration is that your dev URLs match your production URLs. https://brands.website.localhost:8080 -> https://brands.website.com

Each project will have complete control over the domain's subpaths and won't clobber other project's routes, which you alluded to with the `/brands` route.